# calling wcf webservice using basichttpbinding without REST or JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, basichttpbinding

I have a wcf webservice that is exposed through wsHTTPBinding and basicHTTPBinding.   The latter specifies it's endpoint address as being "/basic" as in the following:

```
    <endpoint address="/basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="theAwesomeBasicHttpServerBinding" contract="LOServices.Proxy.ServiceContracts.ILOService">
      <identity>
        <servicePrincipalName value="HTTP/MY_MACHINE_NAME" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
```

the binding is defined as follows:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="theAwesomeBasicHttpServerBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

I am trying to call one of the webmethods using jquery.  Because this is over a basicHTTPBinding and not RESTful, therefore, I will not be using JSON.  I consequently am building the request XML from a previous (successful) call that I made to the service through wcf test client:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ILOService/GetLoanActions</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetLoanActions xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <request xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LOServices.Proxy.Requests" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d4p1:AssociationNumber>3</d4p1:AssociationNumber>
        <d4p1:IgnoreWarnings>false</d4p1:IgnoreWarnings>
      </request>
    </GetLoanActions>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The actual javascript that I am using therefore is structured as follows:

```
        function callWs() {
            var theRequest = " \
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \
  <s:Header> \
    <Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none\">http://tempuri.org/ILOService/GetLoanActions</Action> \
  </s:Header> \
  <s:Body> \
    <GetLoanActions xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"> \
      <request xmlns:d4p1=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LOServices.Proxy.Requests\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"> \
        <d4p1:AssociationNumber>3</d4p1:AssociationNumber> \
        <d4p1:IgnoreWarnings>false</d4p1:IgnoreWarnings> \
      </request> \
    </GetLoanActions> \
  </s:Body> \
</s:Envelope>";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/LOServices/Services/LOService.svc/basic",
                data: theRequest,
                timeout: 10000,
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                async: false
            });
        }
```

I'm unfortunate enough to receive a "Bad Request" from the wcf service when I run it in this fashion, however, and that doesn't leave me with much to follow up on.

I've been struggling to try to make this work for at least 3 hours now, so if anyone has ideas, please feel free to jump in with some suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For BasicHttpBinding requests, you need to set the SOAPAction header in the HTTP request (that will define which operation should receive the message).

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/LOServices/Services/LOService.svc/basic",
      data: theRequest,
      timeout: 10000,
      contentType: "text/xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      async: false,
      headers: { "SOAPAction": "http://tempuri.org/Contract/Operation" }
    });
```

Notice that the `headers` option is new in jQuery 1.5, so if you're using an older one, you'll need to use the `beforeSend` function for that.

Also, you should be able to get more information in the future for errors such as "Bad Request" or "Internal Server Error" by [enabling tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) for WCF - the trace will contain more detailed information about the problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to hear. THank you @carlosfigueira.

It's also worth noting that I had to remove the <s:Header> tag (and children) in order to get it to work;  basicHTTPBinding didn't like it.